# How to use multiple commands after "||" in Bash

Tags: bash

Imagine the code:

```
ls || echo "Unable to execute ls (returned non zero)"
```

What if I needed to execute more commands like:

```
ls || echo "this is echo 1" <some operator> echo "this is echo 2" <some operator> exit 1
```

in C (assumming I have a function `ls`) I could do (even if it looks insane):

```
ls() || (command1() && command2());
```

but I doubt I can use parentheses like this in bash.

I know I can create a Bash function that would contain these commands, but what if I needed to combine this with `exit 1` (exit in a function would exit that function, not whole script)?

Comment: Why not just `ls || (echo 0 && echo 1)`? Using `false || (echo 0 && echo 1)` you can see both echos are executed.

Comment: yes but what I need is to exit the script on error as well as to print the reason why it failed, doing exit in () brackets spawn a subshell, and exit 1 in there exit the subshell not the main script

Comment: Replace the () by {} and append a ;: `ls || { echo 0 && echo 1; }`

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can [group](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Grouping) multiple commands within `{ }`.  Saying:

```
some_command || { command1; command2; }
```

would execute `command1` and `command2` if `some_command` exited with a non-zero return code.

> `{}`
>
> ```
> { list; }
> ```
>
> Placing a list of commands between curly braces causes the list to be executed in the current shell context. No subshell is created. The
>   semicolon (or newline) following list is required.

Comment: I am getting syntax error `syntax error near unexpected token ||` on this line (ms is a function I declared in script) `cd ~/repo/folder || { ms "Unable to switch to build directory"; || exit 1; }`

Comment: @Petr You need to get rid of the `;` before `||` within `{ }`. Moreover, it seems that you wanted to use `&&` instead of `||`.  Say: `cd ~/repo/* || { ms "Unable to switch to build directory" && exit 1; }` instead.

Comment: @Petr No idea about what?  `||` is a command separator, so you don't need to put the `;` before it.  Putting a `;` before `||` __is__ an error (which is exactly what the shell told you).

Answer (score 18):

In fact, you *can* use parentheses. They just tell bash "run the commands in a subshell". You can also use curlies:

```
ls || { echo 1 ; echo 2 ; }
```

Note that `;` or a newline before the closing curlie is *not* optional.

Comment: @Petr: `(exit)` does not exit the main shell. `{ exit; }` does.

Comment: @Petr When you use curly braces `{ }`, the commands are executed in the current shell context.